# Magento 2 sales_order_save_before event getting null value

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am trying to save custom data through observer , My observer is triggering but inside execute method I am getting null.

Observer class

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class PaymentAssignData implements ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        //die(__METHOD__);
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }


    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     $quote = $order->getQuote();

       var_dump($quote);exit;



    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't get the quote using `sales_order_save_before` you can only get the order:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

Then after that you can do:

```
$quoteId = $order->getQuoteId();
```

Comment: I did the same but getting "NUll" value only.

Comment: post your updated code. @rajatkara

Comment: please check the updated code

Comment: @rajatkara your updated quote is wrong you cannot call `$order->getQuote()` you can only call `$order->getQuoteId()`

Comment: I think he is not Interested for the answer @RaphaelatDigitalPianism

Comment: i want to save my custom field data to quote_payment and sales_order_payment table.how to do that ?